# Understanding TimeseriesGenerator with CNN Conv1D

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series

I'm new to Keras and to CNN and I don't understand how to correctly structure the CNN network.

Context:
I use a time series of 39 features and I want to use 3 lags of data. Also, my problem is a multistep outputs, and so I want to predict 48 outputs.
I use TimeseriesGenerator to create model inputs (using [this article for reference](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-develop-convolutional-neural-network-models-for-time-series-forecasting/)).

Here is my code:

```
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(
        inputs,
        outputs,
        length=6,
        batch_size=1,
)
```

Here is my model construction:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(
    Conv1D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=5,
        strides=1,
        activation="relu",
        padding="valid",
        input_shape=(6, 39),
        use_bias=True,
    )
)
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(
    Conv1D(
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=5,
        strides=1,
        activation="relu",
        padding="valid",
        use_bias=True,
    )
)
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(units=100, activation="relu",))
model.add(Dense(units=self.__n_steps_out, activation="softmax",))


model.compile(
    optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
)


model.fit_generator(
    generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=100,
)
```

Problem:
I understood that kernel size (with valid padding) cannot be higher than the number of lags specified in the ts generator.
But I have a dimensional error when setting the kernel size=5 < nb_lags=6:

```
ValueError: Negative dimension size caused by subtracting 5 from 1 for '{{node conv1d_1/conv1d}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true](conv1d_1/conv1d/ExpandDims, conv1d_1/conv1d/ExpandDims_1)' with input shapes: [?,1,1,64], [1,5,64,64].
```

I've found that my CNN structure is correct only when kernel_size is set to 2, don't get why it's working but not when I increase the value...

Can anyone explain me the inputs and outputs of TimeseriesGenerator and Conv1D layers?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to the fact that you too aggressively reduce dimensions. Since your input dimension is `(6, 39)`, then after first `Conv1D` it has dimension `(2, 64)`, and then after first `MaxPooling1D` it reduces to `(1, 64)`. Thus after second `Conv1D` with `kernel_size=5` and `padding='valid'` you would get `(1-5, 64)` dimensions what the error actually trying say to you.

Instead of `Conv1D` and `Maxpooling1D` you may use `Conv2D` and `Maxpooling2D` respectively and set 1s at the time dimension. Here is the example how to do so:

```
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':

    inputs = np.random.rand(1000, 39, 1)
    outputs = np.random.rand(1000, 1, 1)

    generator = TimeseriesGenerator(
        inputs,
        outputs,
        length=6,
        batch_size=10,
    )

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(
        Conv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=(1, 5),
            strides=1,
            activation="relu",
            padding="valid",
            input_shape=(6, 39, 1),
            use_bias=True,
        )
    )
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))
    model.add(
        Conv2D(
            filters=64,
            kernel_size=(1, 5),
            strides=1,
            activation="relu",
            padding="valid",
            use_bias=True,
        )
    )
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(units=100, activation="relu", ))
    model.add(Dense(units=1, activation="softmax", ))

    model.summary()

    model.compile(
        optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"]
    )

    model.fit_generator(
        generator, steps_per_epoch=1, epochs=100,
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I understand better what was wrong.
Just one more question because I really don't see how we can do this. When you say use a 2D convolution with time as the dimension, what do you mean? Do I need to put the timestamp of my data as an additional column? What does it mean for the network?

Comment: @hotuagia You have multi-valued time series which you split into smaller windows giving you inputs of shape (T,S) where T is a time dimension and S are some values. Thus, you may treat it as an 2D image and apply 2D Convs and Maxpooling just in the second dimension (corresponding to S). I guessed it was your initial idea.

Comment: I have a time series containing several features. Based on my statistical analysis, I consider the 6 past values to be useful in predicting the next one. So I use a window of 6 values that I pass to the network. I still don't understand what the second dimension of time could represent.

Comment: @hotuagia Ok, so if you want 1D Conv and Maxpooling in time dimension just change in your code `padding="valid"` in Conv layers into `padding="same"`

Comment: thanks, it's finally working now! thanks for all your answers